# Etymology of "Володино"

Tags: этимология, toponyms

Numerous villages are called "Володино", does it mean something?

Answer (score 6):

Володя means Вова, which is a nickname for Владимир. Володин**о** (*село*) = Vladimir's (village). This is the meaning of the name of the villages. But who exactly this Vladimir was is a mystery.

Comment: 1) Володя is not a nickname. Nickname in English means [прозвище] or [кличка] or [погоняло]. Jonny is not a nickname for John. Teddy is not a nickname for Ted. 2) By saying that [Володино] = Vladimir's non-Russian speakers might think that this village belongs to Vladimir, that this village is Vladimir's property, but this is not so. In English it is Saint Petersburg, but not Saint Peter's Burg which is the real root for the name of St.Petersburg. 3) I doubt that [-о] at the end stricktly means [село]. There are a lot of [деревня Володино].

Comment: @Tchibi-kun https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Jack-a-nickname-for-John https://nameberry.com/nametalk/threads/111642-What-can-Teddy-be-a-nickname-for I understand the Russian terms you are talking about, and I agree that кличка is the first translation Russian speakers think of hearing the word nickname. However, the English word has more meanings. And I know what I'm talking about. Please visit the Collins English dictionary - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nickname and scroll down to see the the definition for "nickname" in British English

Comment: @Tchibi-kun you will see that "nickname" can mean a shortened or familiar form of a person's name: Jo is a nickname for Josephine. 2) My answer was not about St.Petersburg - that's a good point though. But I really think that Володино comes from Volodya's. Sure, St.Petersburg is a different thing and it deserves a different discussion. 3) Thank you for sharing your doubts about "о" - even though it may be possible to say деревня Володино, I think this "o" in the name has something to do with the gender of "село" which Volodino was supposed to modify. If it doesn't, what is this "o" for?

Comment: Володя absolutely is a nickname for Владимир. Johnny absolutely is a nickname for John. And Bill is a nickname for William.  And so on and so forth. While "nickname" might not be all that often used for shortened or abbreviated forms of a full name, the usage is correct. And it's not archaic either.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonny petname, not a nickname.

Comment: @Tchibi-kun I'm not sure it's wise to argue if you trust Wikipedia more than a dictionary. But, OK. Click on the pet name link in that Wikipedia article - and this is what you've got: A hypocorism (/haɪˈpɒkərɪzəm/ hy-POK-ər-iz-əm; from Ancient Greek ὑποκόρισμα (hypokorisma), from ὑποκορίζεσθαι (hypokorizesthai), meaning 'to use child-talk'[1]), also called a hypocoristicon, is a diminutive form of a name. Hypocorisms include pet names or calling names,[2] often a diminutive or augmentative form of a word or given name when used as a NICKNAME or term of endearment.

Comment: @Tchibi-kun you are learning Japanese, aren't you? The Japanese word for "nickname / pet name" is 愛称(あいしょう). See the definition - https://jisho.org/search/nickname. 愛称 :pet name; NICKNAME; name used to indicate AFFECTION, INTIMACY, INFORMALITY, etc.​ I hope it's convincing enough. If not, it's too bad. Good luck anyway!

Answer (score 5):

"Named" names of russian viliges  originates from:

1. family names of local landlords (помещики) ("Володино" - Володин (Volodin's), "Осипово" - Осипов (Osipоv's)).
2. Saints names ("Анненково" - st. Ann , "Николаево" - st. Nicolas).
3. Some arbitrary names given by landlords voluntary. A village may be named after his son, some favorite artist, ancient greek philosopher or just a dog ("Шариково" - "Шарик" is a common dog's name)

Answer (score 2):

I fully agree with the explanation provided here: usually, one would expect "Володино" to provene from "Володя" or "Володин".

Still, the possibility of a different origin should be explored on those special occasions when the said toponym is found at a narrow isthmus separating historical waterways. Across such places, boats were transported by dragging (in Russian: "волоком"). So the nearby toponyms may carry this root, Вышний Волочёк serving as a proverbial example. A village originally called, say, "Волокино" or "Волочино" might have, at later times, been renamed into "Володино", had  this name sound more pleasant to the ear of a local landlord.

Once again, this is solely an option -- but worth checking in certain specific cases.